# Is there any way I can use #define directives to define printf functions?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

below is just a simple program i'm working on, I need to take all the printf and define it in the directives.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define name(parameter) printf("......")

main(){
...
}
```

how do I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FICA_PERCENTAGE 0.0765
#define HOURS_WORKED(int hours_worked) printf("\nHours Worked:  %d\n", hours_worked)
#define HOURLY_RATE(float hourly_rate) printf("Hourly Rate:  $%5.2f\n", hourly_rate)
#define GROSS_PAY(float gross_pay) printf("Gross PAy:  $%5.2f\n", gross_pay)
#define FICA_DEDUCTION(float fica_deduction) printf("FICA deduction:  $%5.2f\n", fica_deduction)
#define NET_PAY(float net_pay) printf("Net Pay:  $%5.2f\n", net_pay)

main(){

    int hours_worked;
    float hourly_rate, gross_pay, net_pay,fica_deduction;

    printf("Simple Payroll Program: \n");
    printf("-------------------\n");
    printf("Enter the number of hrs workrd: ");
    scanf("%d", &hoursWorked);
    printf("Enter the hourly rte of pay: ");
    scanf("%f", &hourly_rate);

    gross_pay = hoursWorked * hourly_rate;
    fica_deduction = gross_pay * FICA_PERCENTAGE;
    net_pay = gross_pay - fica_deduction;

    HOURS_WORKED;
    HOURLY_RATE;
    GROSS_PAY;
    FICA_DEDUCTION;
    NET_PAY;

    /*printf("\nHours Worked:  %d\n", hoursWorked);
    printf("Hourly Rate:  $%5.2f\n", hourly_rate);
    printf("Gross PAy:  $%5.2f\n", gross_pay);
    printf("FICA deduction:  $%5.2f\n", fica_deduction);
    printf("Net Pay:  $%5.2f\n", net_pay);*/

    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>

#define FICA_PERCENTAGE 0.0765
main(){

    int hours_worked;
    float hourly_rate, gross_pay, net_pay,fica_deduction;

    printf("Simple Payroll Program: \n");
    printf("-------------------\n");
    printf("Enter the number of hrs workrd: ");
    scanf("%d", &hoursWorked);
    printf("Enter the hourly rte of pay: ");
    scanf("%f", &hourly_rate);

    gross_pay = hoursWorked * hourly_rate;
    fica_deduction = gross_pay * FICA_PERCENTAGE;
    net_pay = gross_pay - fica_deduction;

    printf("\nHours Worked:  %d\n", hoursWorked);
    printf("Hourly Rate:  $%5.2f\n", hourly_rate);
    printf("Gross PAy:  $%5.2f\n", gross_pay);
    printf("FICA deduction:  $%5.2f\n", fica_deduction);
    printf("Net Pay:  $%5.2f\n", net_pay);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define HOURS_WORKED(hours_worked) printf("\nHours Worked:  %d\n", (hours_worked))` Then just call `HOURS_WORKED (hours_worked);`

Comment: i need to define, all the printf function I used later in the program, outside of main. In the directives.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  It doesn't add any functionality; it makes the code harder to read and more complicated to debug, maintain and improve.   What possible reason would you have for such a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a good use case for a macro.  It just obfuscates your code and adds some complexity where it isn't needed.  However, if you're committed to this, you need to make a few changes.

First of all, macro arguments do not have a type:

```
#define HOURS_WORKED(hours_worked) printf("\nHours Worked:  %d\n", hours_worked)
```

Secondly, when you invoke the macro, you need to provide the argument as well:

```
HOURS_WORKED(hoursWorked);
```

Remember, function-like macros are not functions - they're just text substitutions.  Macro arguments are not evaluated, they are simply expanded in place.  That is, if you invoke `HOURS_WORKED` as

```
HOURS_WORKED(n * 40);
```

then it will expand to

```
printf("\nHours Worked:  %d\n", n * 40)
```

To avoid precedence and parsing issues, it's often a good idea to wrap your macro argument in parens:

```
#define HOURS_WORKED(hours_worked) printf("\nHours worked: %d\n", (hours_worked) );
```

Comment: also consider changing `#define` to `void` and adding a set of braces

Answer (score 0):

Macros perform substitution, with optional parameter substitution

```
#define X yyyy
```

will replace occurrences of the token `X` with `yyyy`.

```
#define X(Y) yyyy Y yyyy
```

will replace occurrences of the parameterized token `X(Foo)` with `yyyy Foo yyyy`.

Taking your first `printf` attempt as an example, it seems you want:

```
#define HOURS_WORKED(Y) \
        printf("\nHours Worked:  %d\n", Y)
```

And then, you would call it like this:

```
HOURS_WORKED(hoursWorked);
```

Your other macros and invocations would need to be adjusted accordingly.